# Tkinter How to fix After issue caused by Recursion

Tags: python, tkinter

```
WORK_MIN = 12
SHORT_BREAK_MIN = 5
LONG_BREAK_MIN = 20
reps = 0


def start_timer():
    global reps
    work_min = WORK_MIN * 60
    long_break = LONG_BREAK_MIN * 60
    short_break = SHORT_BREAK_MIN * 60
    while True:
        reps += 1
        if reps % 8 == 0:
            countdown(long_break)
        elif reps % 2 == 1:
            countdown(work_min)
        else:
            countdown(short_break)


def countdown(second_count):

    minute_time = int(second_count / 60)

    # minute_time =  math.floor(second_count / 60)
    if len(str(minute_time)) == 1:
        minute_time = f"0{minute_time}"

    second_time = second_count % 60
    if len(str(second_time)) == 1:
        second_time = f"0{second_time}"

    if second_count > 0:
        window.after(1000, countdown, second_count - 1)



window = Tk()
window.title("Pomodoro Practice")
window.config(padx=100, pady=50, bg=YELLOW)
window.minsize(width=300, height=300)

start_timer()

window.mainloop()
```

Whenever I run this code, it skips over window.after(1000, countdown, second_count - 1) and returns back to the while loop in start_timer(). I would like the countdown function to be called recursively after waiting for a second until second count == 0.

Comment: Do you have `window.mainloop()` or `window.update()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: I have window.mainloop() at the bottom on my code, edited for clairty

Comment: As @MichaelGuidry tried to point out: Your loop (`while True`) is infinite. That means that your gui isn't going to update. Also you are calling `countdown` which is a loop every time the `while True` loop runs.

Comment: Doesn't the start_timer function go into countdown which calls itself recursively and updates the gui? Why does the start timer function continue running after the countdown function has been called which causes the countdown function to stop calling itself?

Comment: That isn't how `.after` works. When you call `.after` it gets appended to a list of instructions to be called later and continues with the code. When the code reaches `window.mainloop()`/`window.update()` again it executes the commands in the list by order. Therefore in your case it will keep appending new instructions each time `countdown` is called.

Comment: Gotcha, so an infinite loop in start_timer() never allows the event processing portion of window.mainloop() to execute so actions are continuously being appended but never executed causing the gui to never update.

Comment: correct. Also when using tkinter you shouldn't use `white True` loops or anything that will run for more than 0.5 sec because your gui will feel laggy. This is because `window.mainloop()`/`window.update()` also update the display and tell Windows that the app is still running so it doesn't say that "This app isn't responding"

Comment: So, when does window.mainloop() execute the processing on the remaining actions?, from my understanding it would process whenever a new function gets called and it isn't time based.

Comment: When `.mainloop()` is called it will run a `while True` loop inside it self. That loop executes all of the actions pending (like `.after` scripts, events, draw the widgets on the screen, tell the OS that it's still responding, ...). After it is done it will wait for the next instructions to be added to the list. Note: `.after` scripts have a time for when they should be executed. If the time isn't right it will skip over those `.after` scrips in the list and continue executing the rest of the items in its to do list.

Comment: So, for clarification, does .mainloop() run concurrently to my main code, and process the requests when the time has come? and Does using a infinite while loop take up too many system resources to let .mainloop() run properly?

Comment: It isn't concurrent. It uses a `while True` infinite loop to handle all events coming in. In that loop it also checks if the time is right to run the `.after` scripts. If in your code you have a `while True` loop, it isn't going to take a lot of resources but generally its bad practise and some times your GUI can hang while the function completes and code execution goes back to the `.mainloop`.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I think I understand. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `break` to the end of all your `while` conditions, and add an `else` condition to the end of `countdown` that restarts `start_timer`.

```py
WORK_MIN = 12
SHORT_BREAK_MIN = 5
LONG_BREAK_MIN = 20
reps = 0


def start_timer():
    global reps
    work_min = WORK_MIN * 60
    long_break = LONG_BREAK_MIN * 60
    short_break = SHORT_BREAK_MIN * 60
    while True:
        reps += 1
        if reps % 8 == 0:
            countdown(long_break)
            break
        elif reps % 2 == 1:
            countdown(work_min)
            break
        else:
            countdown(short_break)
            break


def countdown(second_count):
    minute_time = int(second_count / 60)

    # minute_time =  math.floor(second_count / 60)
    if len(str(minute_time)) == 1:
        minute_time = f"0{minute_time}"

    second_time = second_count % 60
    if len(str(second_time)) == 1:
        second_time = f"0{second_time}"

    canvas.itemconfig(timer_text, text=f"{minute_time}:{second_time}")
    if second_count > 0:
        window.after(1000, countdown, second_count - 1)
    else:
        start_timer()

start_timer()
```

You can also just get rid of the `while` loop entirely, but still add the condition to the end of `countdown`. However, if you are going to "trim the fat", trim it all. It's interesting that you work for 12 minutes, break for 5 (3 times) and then you work for 12 and break for 20. So, in 83 minutes you work 48 and break for 35. Sounds like a helluva job. If you worked for me you could have a `float('inf')` minute break ... cause you'd be fired. :D

```py
import tkinter as tk
    
window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()
timer_text = canvas.create_text(50, 50, font='Helvetica 24 bold')

reps = 0

def start_timer():
    global reps
    reps += 1
    if reps % 8 == 0:
        countdown(20*60)
    elif reps % 2 == 1:
        countdown(12*60)
    else:
        countdown(5*60)

def countdown(seconds):
    canvas.itemconfig(timer_text, text=f"{seconds//60:02}:{seconds%60:02}")
    window.after(1000, countdown, seconds-1) if seconds else start_timer()

start_timer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Removing the while true and breaks from the start_timer function and adding else: start_timer()  to countdown() gives the correct result with the window showing the countdown. Thanks :)

Comment: @JerryLaquin ~ My method works fine. I rewrote his code in completed form with the `window`, `canvas` and `timer_text` included before I posted my answer. I don't think it works. I'm positive it does. I'll even include it in my answer. You can try it yourself.

Comment: Tried it and it works as well, Thanks for the help

Comment: @JerryLaquin ~ I'm sorry. I misunderstood. I thought you were some other user trying to tell me that my code is wrong. You are correct, you can just get rid of the while and breaks.